# Is possible redirect url when it fails or goes to catch?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I have 5 types of base url.

Ex: url1, url2, url3, url4, url5

The plot is when the promise fails then the url will change and re-run until the promise success then stop.

```
const checkToken = async (address: string, chainId: number | null): Promise<boolean> => {
    try {
        const baseUrl = url1 ;
        //.... some code;
        return something;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
        //change baseUrl and try again
    }
}
```

Is there a way?

Comment: It's not possible to tell what URL you want to change or what to redirect.

Comment: Is there another way to handle it?

Comment: Hi, what does changing `baseURL` mean in your context? Is it some kind of API `baseURL`?

Comment: yes, api baseurl

Comment: @Fery1320 Maybe you'll need a recursive promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar result by using recursive method. If the promise is rejected, calling the function itself with the next URL will do the trick. E.g,

```
const mockAPICall = async (baseURL: string) => {
  switch (baseURL) {
    case "baseURL-1":
      return Promise.reject("baseURL-1");
    case "baseURL-2":
      return Promise.resolve("baseURL-2"); // Mock second URL to be working.
    case "baseURL-3":
      return Promise.reject("baseURL-3");
    case "baseURL-4":
      return Promise.reject("baseURL-4");
    case "baseURL-5":
      return Promise.reject("baseURL-5");
    default:
      return Promise.reject();
  }
};

const baseURLs = [
  "baseURL-1",
  "baseURL-2",
  "baseURL-3",
  "baseURL-4",
  "baseURL-5"
] as const;

const App = () => {
  const checkToken = async (index = 0): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((res, rej) =>
      mockAPICall(baseURLs[index])
        .then(res)
        .catch(() => {
          if (index < baseURLs.length) {
            return checkToken(index + 1)
              .then(res)
              .catch(rej); // We proceed to test with the next url.
          } else {
            rej(); // Non of the urls work, we reject the promise here.
          }
        })
    );

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          checkToken().then((baseURL) => alert(`BaseURL '${baseURL}' worked`))
        }
      >
        Check Token
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit 74470303]

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful but i'm still confused because baseurl-2 is set manually resolve,
what if programmatically ?

Comment: @Fery1320 Hi, the `mockAPICall` function is actually just a mock function which simulates API call. In your case, you will actually call your API and Promise could either resolve or reject depending on the API response. Since I do not have access to your API, I can only do a mock function to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: I see, thankyou so much brother I have found the way